# import named range from excel to access

Tags: excel, vba

I need to import one line of data from an excel sheet to an Access database table.
I have preconfigured the line of data so that the cells correspond to the fields in the Access table.  The data has been named as a range.
Using the Access GUI, I can append a table, and it gives me the option to import a range, rather than a table.
Is there a way to do this via VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is... more than one way, actually. I would probably do something like this in an Access VBA macro. First open the Excel workbook using COM automation:

```
Dim xl As Object
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 'open Excel
Dim wb as Object, ws as Object
Set wb = xl.WorkBooks.Open("c:\mypath\myfile.xlsx") 'open WorkBook
Set ws = wb.worksheets("My Sheet") 'Select WorkSheet
```

Then get data from your named range.

```
Data1 = ws.Range("myRangeName").Cells(1,1)
Data2 = ws.Range("myRangeName").Cells(1,2)
Data3 = ws.Range("myRangeName").Cells(1,3)
Data4 = ws.Range("myRangeName").Cells(1,4)
```

Then do any needed manipulation of the Data as required before inserting in an Access SQL statement (e.g., format dates, deal with special characters). Finally, insert the data with SQL string.

```
qs = "INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4) VALUES ('" & Data1 & "','" & Data2 & "','" & Data3 & "','" & Data4 & "');"
CurrentDb.Execute qs
```

This example assumes that all fields will receive string data.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  This looks like exactly what I was trying to do.